# Value from checkboxes not being returned

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a couple of checkboxes that I'm trying to loop through and get the value of. However, my JS function is not returning the value when checking a box. I am very new to JS and would really appreciate any help! Code shown below:

```
<body>
    <script src="racquetObjects.js"></script>
    <div class="mainContainer">
      <div class="selectors">
        <form action="">
          <div class="brandName">
            <input type="checkbox" id="babolat" value="Babolat" />
            <label for="babolat">Babolat</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="wilson" value="Wilson" />
            <label for="wilson">Wilson</label>
          </div>
          <div class="characteristics">
            <input type="checkbox" id="power" value="Power" />
            <label for="power">Power</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="control" value="" />
            <label for="control">Control</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="popular" value="" />
            <label for="popular">Popular</label>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Find" id="search" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="racquetContainer"></div>
      <div class="bench"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="racquetFinder.js"></script>
  </body>

const brandNameCB = document.querySelector(".brandName").children;

function isChecked() {
  for (var i = 0; i < brandNameCB.length; i++) {
    if (
      brandNameCB[i].tagName === "INPUT" &&
      brandNameCB[i].type === "checkbox"
    ) {
      if (brandNameCB[i].checked) {
        console.log(brandNameCB[i].value + " is Selected!);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger isChecked using some event. Onchange of the input would be a good choice.

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="wilson" value="Wilson" onchange="isChecked()"/>
```

Add this attribute to the checkboxes through which you want to trigger the event.

Also your code will work only for the brandNames right now because you are using brandNameCB. Not for characterisitcs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to add an event listener:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".brandName input[type=checkbox]").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed getAttribute() function cause .type and .checked is not in the specification. Try this:

```js
function isChecked() {
  for (var i = 0; i < brandNameCB.length; i++) {
    if (
      brandNameCB[i].tagName === "INPUT" &&
      brandNameCB[i].getAttribute(type) === "checkbox"
    ) {
      if (brandNameCB[i].getAttribute(checked)) {
        console.log(brandNameCB[i].getAttribute(value) + " is Selected!);
      }
    }
  }
}
```